# React Router url properties using index/:id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, router

I seem to be doing everything right, but I've been getting this `strict MIME type` and `404` error which I don't know why I'm getting. I new to React and routing, I really got stuck here.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "../components/Home";
import Contact from "../components/Contact";
import Portfolio from "../components/Portfolio";
import NotFound from "../components/NotFound";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Portfoliopage from "../components/PortfolioPage";

const AppRouters = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        //*I tried using this component directly with the /:id here...*
        <Route path="/portfolio/:id" component={Portfolio} />
        *//I also tried this nested routing here*
        <Route path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio}>
          <Route path="/:id" component={Portfoliopage} />
        </Route>
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

[This is the error that I get when I run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vlbcg.png)

Comment: I think the error is in your html file. Have you tried writing `<script src="/bundle.js"></script>` instead?

Comment: Did you use create-react-app to create your app?

Comment: @Tholle the script tag is right in my html code. the problem has to do with the 'portfolio/:id' . i tried using nested route also, it didn't work still

Comment: @dnp1204 No i din't, i started from scratch

Comment: @sapphire Yes, but the browser is trying to load your JavaScript bundle from `/portfolio/bundle.js` which would indicate you have `bundle.js` in your HTML file instead of `/bundle.js`.

Comment: @Tholle Oh!, that works, thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error indicates that your `bundle.js` is loaded relative to the current url. Add `/` to the beginning of the `src` to make it absolute instead.

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```